How to resolve the residual versus predicted quantile devation (Dharma plot)?
I have been trying to perform beta regression modeling with random effects. I have sex ratio (0.561, 0.765 etc) as the
response variable, and climatic variables + years (1970-2021) as predictor variables. Different farms were used as random effects. I used glmmTMB + beta family + logit for modeling. All explanatory variables were standardised.
But the residual plot shows significant quantile deviation. May I know why it is happening?

The predictor variables were standardized
No transformation of response variable


The first and obvious issue is that beta regression isn't suitable for modelling ratios. Please clarify: Your dependent variable is indeed a ratio and not a proportion? Also, "beta regression" is not sufficient to describe the model. What is your link-function? Maybe try a different a link function. Consider if you might have missing predictors. If you use time as a predictor, maybe that relationship isn't linear. How did you model the precision parameter? ...

Dependent variable is ratio (0.543, 0.843 etc). Link function is logit. I have years as a predictior (but removing it didn’t help).

DV is a sex ratio.

I used glmmTMB with beta family and spatial groups as random effect

Do you have the counts or just the ratios? If you have the counts, you could use a logistic regression with random effects.

I can extract counts for males and females. May I know exactly which package and waht function would be ideal for it ?

I'd use glmer from the lme4 package.
